# Not able to remove from an ArrayList

Tags: java

```
 import java.util;  
 class Driver{

 public static void main(String[] args) {
      ArrayList<String> lstStr = new ArrayList<String>();
      lsstStr.add("A");
      lsstStr.add("B");
      lsstStr.add("C");
      for(Iterator<String> it = lstStr.Iterator(); it.hasNext();)
      {
          str = it.next();
          if(str.equals("B")){lstStr.remove(str);}
      }
      for(Iterator<String> it = lstStr.Iterator(); it.hasNext();)
      {
        System.out.println(it.next());
      }
 }
 }
```

This is not removing "B" from the list. Why Str is not equal to "B" when loop runs second time.Why?

Comment: Your code won't currently compile, so it won't show anything. Please give an example which compiles, first. You're clearly not running the code you've posted, so we don't know what code actually *are* running.

Comment: This code will result concurrent modification exception, as the iterator becomes unusable after you have removed the element from the collection. You do not tell us this so probably you have not even tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't remove an item from a collection you're iterating over *except* using [`Iterator.remove`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29) - you'll get a `ConcurrentModificationException`. So your loop would be something like:

```
for (Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    String value = iterator.next();
    if (value.equals("B")) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Of course, you should use `removeAll` to *just* remove all items with a specific value - but the above approach is the one to use if you need to remove based on some condition other than simple equality (e.g. "remove all values with a length greater than 5". Another option is to collect all the values to remove in a new collection, and then call `removeAll` afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

Try this : It will remove all occurrence of "B" from your List without any loop.

```
lstStr.removeAll(Collections.singleton("B"));
```

Comment: import java.util.*;
 class Drive{

 public static void main(String[] args) {
      ArrayList<String> lstStr = new ArrayList<String>();
      lstStr.add("A");
      lstStr.add("R");
      lstStr.add("C");
      String str;
      for(Iterator<String> it = lstStr.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
      { 
       str = it.next();
          if(str.equals("R")){lstStr.remove(it);}
      }
      for(Iterator<String> it = lstStr.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
      {
        System.out.println(it.next());
      }
 }
 }

Comment: @Brometheus: Please don't add code in comments like that - especially with no indication whatsoever *why* you're doing so. If you want to change your question (which you should - to make it compile, if nothing else) you should edit the question, not add meaningless comments on answers or asking a new question in a separate post.

Answer (score 0):

Use the iterator's `remove` method. It will remove the element from the collection.