# ArrayList elements not removed

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
class Drive{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> lstStr = new ArrayList<String>();
        lstStr.add("A");
        lstStr.add("R");
        lstStr.add("C");
        String str;
        for(Iterator<String> it = lstStr.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {   
            str = it.next();
            if(str.equals("R")) {
                lstStr.remove(it);
            }
        }
        for(Iterator<String> it = lstStr.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            System.out.println(it.next());
        }
    }
}
```

Couldn't understand what's happening, why R is not being removed from ArrayList?

Comment: huh? http://stackoverflow.com/q/15996981/106261

Comment: Are you serious? You posted the same question 20 mins ago, reposting doesn't help you finding the answer, delete this question.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove()

Comment: @Harlandraka apparently it does...

Answer (score 3):

```
if(str.equals("R"))
    lstStr.remove(it);
```

Above should be :

```
if(str.equals("R"))
    it.remove();
```

Comment: i think the remove method always requires a parameter when used for an ArryaList.

Comment: It should be iterator.remove();

Comment: @Brometheus: But that's not calling `remove()` on the `ArrayList` - it's calling it on the iterator. Just as I did in my answer to your earlier question.

Comment: @Brometheus I think you are confused with Arraylist#remove(element) And Iterator#remove().

Answer (score 2):

Please use the `Iterator`'s remove method when you are trying to remove anything from `List` safely . As per the API , `void remove()` : Removes from the underlying collection the last element returned by the iterator (optional operation). This method can be called only once per call to next. The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified while the iteration is in progress in any way other than by calling this method.

The code of yours needs minor correction :

```
for(Iterator<String> it = lstStr.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
{ 
    str = it.next();
    // instead of iterator "it" put string "str" as argument to the remove()
    if(str.equals("R")){lstStr.remove(str);}
 }
```

Though the above code will work in your case , but there are lot of edge cases where it will fail . The best way to do this is :

```
for(Iterator<String> it = lstStr.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
{ 
    str = it.next();
    // use iterator's remove()
    if(str.equals("R")){ it.remove();}
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the iterator's remove method like,

```
List<String> lstStr = new ArrayList<String>();
lstStr.add("A");
lstStr.add("R");
lstStr.add("C");
String str;

for(Iterator<String> it = lstStr.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
{ 
    str = it.next();
    if(str.equals("R"))
    {
        it.remove();
    }
}

for(Iterator<String> it = lstStr.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
{
    System.out.println(it.next());
}
```

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator
>   methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any
>   time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the
>   **iterator's own remove or add methods**, the iterator will throw a
>   ConcurrentModificationException.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: Why lstStr.remove("R") doesn't work?

Comment: In your question, you're supplying `iterator` as a parameter to the `remove()` method which is wrong - `lstStr.remove(it);`.